# Mean return time in Markov chain

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains, markov-process

Given the following Markov chain:

$p_{0,1}=1$ (if we are in state 0, we must go to state 1)

$p_{i,i+1}=p_{i,i-1}=0.5$

There are infinitely (countably) many states.

I assume that $X_0=0$ and define $T=\inf\{n>0 : X_n=0\}$ the return time to state $0$.

I want to calculate $P(T=k)$ (My goal is to calculate the expected value of T). I think that $P(T=k)=0$ if $k$ is odd, but I have no idea how to calculate it exactly, I tried to think about $T$ as "almost" geometric law, with probability of $1/2^k$ to "win" at each step, but it's not fixed probability so I am not even sure it is defined...

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to calculate the expectation directly than it is to write down the distribution. This is usually the case.

Since you haven't said that much about what you've tried yet, let me start with a hint. Try to calculate the expected time to hit $\{ 0,n \}$ starting from $x$ with $0<x<n$. Then send $n \to \infty$. You can set up a system of equations for this problem by conditioning on the first step, by using the total expectation formula and the Markov property.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the comment. I followed your advice, but there is still one thing I am not sure of : how can I calculate the stationary distribution of this process?

Comment: @MrY Find the transition probability "matrix" $P$ (it is technically infinite dimensional, so there are some concerns here) and solve the equation $\pi P = \pi$. (In my convention here, $P_{ij}$ is the probability to go from $i$ to $j$.) A solution to this equation is an invariant measure. When dealing with infinitely many states, there may be an invariant measure even when there is no invariant distribution, in the sense that any invariant measure cannot be normalized. I suspect that this will happen in your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I prove that there is no invariant distribution?

Comment: @MrY Find an invariant measure; show that it is unique up to a constant factor; show that the sum of the entries in the measure is always $\infty$ (or $0$, in the trivial case of the zero measure, which is always invariant); conclude that none of the invariant measures can be normalized into a distribution. In the related problem where there is no "wall" at zero, the invariant measure is the uniform measure, which is easily seen to be impossible to normalize.

Comment: Hey, I tried calculating directly the expectatio, but for the finite case (you proposed taking the finite case with n-> infinity)- what are the transition probablies of the last state? (for the infinite case it's half go back and half move forward). In additio,  why does the limit equal to the real expectation?

Comment: @MrY State $n$ doesn't need a transition probability, because the expected time to hit $\{ 0,n \}$ starting from $n$ is zero. As for the limit issue, the expected time to hit $0$ is bounded below by the expected time to hit $\{ 0,n \}$ for any $n$, so if this blows up then you're done. They are actually equal, even when the time is finite, which is just slightly harder to prove.

Comment: Why does the probability to hit {0,n} is smaller than the probability to hit 0? The probability to hit {0,n} is : hitting 0 or hitting n, which is higher/equal to the probability to hit 0.

Comment: also, I don't understand how you can say that the expected value to hit n is 0 : if it's true, than since the chain is irreducible, all states have finite expected value and the chain has stationary distribution (which is not true)

Comment: @MrY I think you misunderstand some things. Let me be explicit. First, the expected time to hit $\{ 0,n \}$ *starting from* $n$ is definitely zero, because you're already there. As for the inequality issue, define $\tau_A=\inf \{ k : X_k \in A \}$ (with the convention $\inf \emptyset = +\infty$). Then $\tau_0 \geq \tau_{\{ 0,n \}}$, again because if you are in $\{ 0 \}$ then you are also in $\{0,n\}$. Hence the same carries through with expectations applied: $E[\tau_0] \geq E[\tau_{\{ 0,n \}}]$ for every $n$. Since the right side is blowing up as $n \to \infty$, the left side must be infinite.